# Minikube Nginx Kubernetes Ingress is Changing the Method of Requests

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I have this ingress configuration file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mylocalhost.info
    http:
      paths:
      # NOTE: this one should come after all other routes. To avoid hijacking requests.
      - path: /api/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-default
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 8080
```

When I turn it on I can get the frontend service working fine. The problem is that when my frontend make an API call to the backend, for some reason the ingress changes the request from GET to POST so my backend returns a server error (405).

How can I configure the ingress to keep the same HTTP method withour changing it to GET?

Frontend Service/Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: frontend
  name: frontend
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: mysecret
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/myimage/frontend:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: frontend
#        resources:
#          requests:
#            cpu: "1.0"
#            memory: "1G"
#          limits:
#            cpu: "1.0"
#            memory: "1G"

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: frontend
  name: frontend
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: frontend
  type: ClusterIP
```

Backend Services and Deployments

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: backend-default
  name: backend-default
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-default
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-default
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: mysecret
      volumes:
      - name: service-account-credentials-volume
        secret:
          secretName: gcp-service-account-credentials
          items:
          - key: sa_json
            path: sa_credentials.json
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/mybackendimage/default:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: backend-default
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: service-account-credentials-volume
          mountPath: /etc/gcp
          readOnly: true
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: backend-default-configmap
        - secretRef:
            name: backend-default-secrets
#        resources:
#          requests:
#            cpu: "1.0"
#            memory: "1G"
#          limits:
#            cpu: "1.0"
#            memory: "1G"
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: backend-default
  name: backend-default
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: backend-default
  type: ClusterIP
```

Relevant logs of the NGINX Ingress controller

```
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:41:12 +0000] "GET /static/js/131.4ccedc61d2caa2c0cdf8.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3182 "http://mylocalhost.info/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 546 0.001 [default-frontend-8080] [] 172.17.0.4:80 3182 0.000 200 fda43aed15c089c7b960f69045c891d2
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:41:24 +0000] "POST /api/v1/user/new HTTP/1.1" 302 301 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 673 0.003 [default-backend-default-8080] [] 172.17.0.9:8080 301 0.004 302 63ae2df926a5acfb96202cad050248ba
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:41:24 +0000] "OPTIONS /api/v1/user/new HTTP/2.0" 204 0 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 338 0.000 [default-backend-default-8080] [] - - - - 2b794c37d70b6138479a5380e0158f18
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:41:24 +0000] "GET /api/v1/user/new HTTP/2.0" 500 22 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 76 0.003 [default-backend-default-8080] [] 172.17.0.9:8080 22 0.004 500 897f92a3049c81139f2e4d0ec93c2427
W0125 20:48:04.814824       8 warnings.go:67] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:51:26 +0000] "GET /user/new HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 701 0.001 [default-frontend-8080] [] 172.17.0.6:80 555 0.000 404 56a62857599a4091e03f25e75b97f7cf
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:51:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 532 0.000 [default-frontend-8080] [] 172.17.0.4:80 555 0.000 404 98bd25020f8d9e0ed8f4dc5a19419563
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:52:00 +0000] "POST /api/v1/user/new HTTP/1.1" 302 301 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 673 0.003 [default-backend-default-8080] [] 172.17.0.9:8080 301 0.004 302 9d60c37ac30eabc384ee815c16940a37
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:20:52:00 +0000] "GET /api/v1/user/new HTTP/2.0" 500 22 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 317 0.010 [default-backend-default-8080] [] 172.17.0.9:8080 22 0.008 500 6a1b724dfca5412bc24bb31c2328b01d
W0125 20:54:53.815210       8 warnings.go:67] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
W0125 21:02:19.816583       8 warnings.go:67] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:21:04:50 +0000] "POST /api/v1/user/new HTTP/1.1" 302 301 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 673 0.002 [default-backend-default-8080] [] 172.17.0.9:8080 301 0.000 302 88b814fc0fadce0cfd62358c64b2fcd9
192.168.49.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:21:04:50 +0000] "GET /api/v1/user/new HTTP/2.0" 500 22 "http://mylocalhost.info/user/new" "Mozilla/5.0
```

Note that the /user/new endpoint is what the frontend is hitting. You can see there's the 302 response.

Comment: can you list your Service and Deployment manifest as well?

Comment: Sure I've added them now.

Comment: Thanks. How do you tell that the request HTTP method was changed from GET to POST?

Comment: I suspect that's the problem because if I inspect the network on my chrome browser I first see a 302 redirect (I'm assuming that's from the Ingress), and the very next request is to the exact same URL but it hace a POST method now. Also, if I use the app without kubernetes, I don't see any redirects when doing the API calls.

Comment: you should be able to see all the requests in the Ingress logs.

Comment: Confirmed, the 302 appears on my ingress controller logs, so it's coming from that.

Comment: Can you add the relevant logs to the question?

Comment: I've added the relevant logs. Thanks!

Comment: To eliminate ingress from potential cause of this can you perform a test with `kubectl port-forward deployment/frontend 8080:80` and see if your front-end and back-end works ok?

Comment: @PabloEstrada Why is the frontend accessing the backend via the Ingress? They are in the same namespace `default` and so you can access each other via the service DNS name only.  The frontend pod can access the backend service via `http://backend-default:8080/` or via the DNS `http://backend-default.default.cluster.local:8080`

Comment: I see thanks for the information. Will let you know if anything of th above works

Comment: Changing the namng of the DNS worked, however it is not a viable solution since we have to changes 100s of endpoint calls in our frontend because we have the same base url for all. One extra, info is that i'm using http and the redirect is changing to https with a 302. I tried to add the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect, and nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect to false but not working either.

Comment: @PabloEstrada Using an Ingress to access a backend service involves an external DNS look up, possibly, and accessing the cluster, again, as a public request, ie from outside the cluster. The normal pattern is once a request get's into your cluster, it should stay within the cluster for all cluster local services.

If by frontend in your last comment, you mean the UI, then the base url provided there should match the one specified by the Ingress.

Answer (score 0):

The frontend should access the backend via the backend Service and not the Ingress. They are in the same namespace default and so you can access each other via the service DNS name only. The frontend pod can access the backend service via `http://backend-default:8080/` or via the DNS `http://backend-default.default.cluster.local:8080`

Ref:
[DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-aaaa-records-1)